# Change one form select option based on other selection

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using this code. I am using internal script.I am Able to see the first selection ; but value of second selection is not changing due to first selection. I may be missing some basic thing. Please help. please provide a working example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#type").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "item1") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option 
                value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item2") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option 
                value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item3") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option 
                value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");
        }
    });

});
</script>
<select id="type">
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>
<select id="size">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not imported jquery that is the problem
Copy and paste the below html code in your html page

```
<html>

<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#type").change(function() {

        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "item1") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item2") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item3") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");
        }
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<select id="type">
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>
<select id="size">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks vignesh..cant thank you enough.. :) i have only one question.. why do we need to import jquery. if i use some other concept of javascript, will this particular jquery work for that code also or i need to import some other jquery for that code ?? thanks in advance

Comment: because all the functions you use like `.html .append` etc are defined only in that jquery which you need to import. Yes it will work. You can mark this answer as accepted answer since its working

Answer (score 1):

check this jsfiddle to see the working example http://jsfiddle.net/YPsqQ/

you need to use

```
 $("#id").change(function() {

//your code here

});
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/YPsqQ/

Comment: i think that i have already used $("#type").change(function() i took the example from that fiddle only but the problem is i am using the internal javascript.can u please run my code in your browser and see if it works for you. if not, what is required to edit?? sorry. i am new to javascript

Comment: You need to specify in the script tag that its javascript
<script type='text/javascript'>
//your script here
</script>
In html5 you can just use script tag

Comment: tried.still not working.request you to please run it on your browser. its very important in my project.Please!!